# Optimisation sub query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, subquery, query-performance

I would like to optimise the query below because it's actually taking 40% of the time in the real one. I HAVE to get the first line in the table 2 for each line in the table 1. The relationship is 1 to N between the tables.

I also tried with a `MIN()` for the subquery but I did not had any gain.

I'm open to any solutions.

1. Is there any ways to put the PK of the table 2 inside an index and link directly the good row of the table 2 to the table 1?
2. Would you do a "performance table" with the good PK of table 2 in it?
3. Would you use a pregenerated/temp table?
4. How would Google do? I'm REALLY INTERESTED!

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.PK = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 sT2.PK 
    FROM TABLE2 sT2 
    WHERE sT2.FK = T1.PK
    ORDER BY sT2.DATE_X
)
```

Comment: The table definitions and execution plan would help. Oh, and the exact SQL-Server version (2000, 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012).

Comment: Sorry I can't give much informations. I need every single idea ;)

Comment: ...as well as existing indexes, and whether you can add indexes...

Comment: Do you **really** need to do a `SELECT * ` ? That pretty much ensures that the query will have to either do a lot of key lookups, or go for a clustered index scan..... try to **limit** the number of columns that you return from your query, and explicitly specify those columns! That might open the opportunity for a *covering* index.

Comment: I'm not using `SELECT *` in the real query. I have to return like 30 columns. Maybe I should check if a covering index on some tables could speedup. Thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE2 sT2 
  WHERE sT2.FK = T1.PK
  ORDER BY sT2.DATE_X
)b
```

Comment: Could you append a bit of explanation?

Comment: I'm supposing the CROSS APPLY will be executed once and produce insane perfo?

Comment: @Naster: `CROSS APPLY` is supposed to work faster in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're doing.  I can't tell if you're trying to `CROSS JOIN` Table1 with a subset of Table2, or if there's actually a relationship there.

The query you listed looks like it's doing a complete implicit `CROSS JOIN` of Table1 and Table2 because your join condition ends up as `T2.PK = T2.PK`, but then you filter the second `T2.PK` with your subquery to those that have a matching `T1.Fk`.  I have to think that the system is running your subquery for every row because it is written in such a confusing manner.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.Pk = T2.Fk
WHERE T2.Date_X = (SELECT MIN(Date_X) FROM Table2 WHERE Fk = T2.Fk)
```

Or this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.Pk = T2.Fk
WHERE T2.Pk IN (SELECT Pk FROM Table2 GROUP BY Fk HAVING Date_X = MIN(Date_X))
```

Comment: Your right, the subquery is running for every row from the master query but it's not doing a CROSS JOIN. There are many rows of table 2 for 1 row of table 1. I have to get the first row of table 2 for the corresponding row of table 1. Doing the correct join in the join clause will in theory perform better then in the where clause because I have like 20 joins and the other joins will be executed on a filtered data. More info of the processing order : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx